# How to create a method or function that has one parameter that can take an object or a variable

Tags: javascript, variables, object, parameters, arguments

I'm wondering how to go about doing this. Not sure what the terminology is so I apologize for that. I've seen this behavior in jQuery when you use the `.css()` method. As you may know already, this method accepts a couple of options:

You can do the following:

```
$("#box").css("background-color", "red");//sets the bg color to red
$("#box").css("background-color");//returns the bg color of #box
var properties = {"background-color" : "red", "width" : 100};
$("#box").css(properties); //sets multiple properties in one call with literal object.
```

So, I'm not so much worried about the getter portion of this functionality. I'm most interested in it's ability to differentiate between a variable and a literal object. I'd like to create a plugin that has the same behavior based on the argument it receives. A simple example would be something like this:

```
function openWindow(URL_OR_OBJECT){
    if(variable){
    window.open(URL_OR_OBJECT);
   return; 
  }
   var opt = URL_OR_OBJECT;
   window.open(opt.url, opt.title, opt.options, opt.replace);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspect the type of the parameter with [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

```
function openWindow(parameter){
    if(typeof parameter == "string"){
        window.open(parameter);
    }
    else if(typeof parameter == "object"){
        window.open(parameter.url, parameter.title, parameter.options, parameter.replace);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `typeof` to see if the argument is a string.

```
if ( typeof URL_OR_OBJECT === "string" ) {
  window.open(URL_OR_OBJECT);
} else { /*...*/ }
```

You can to be a little cautious using this because `typeof new String("hello")` is `"object"`. But I don't think too many people declare a string that way.

typeof docs on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Answer (score 0):

While I have not looked at the source code in particular, I presume it is structured something similar to this:

```
function css(bgcolor_or_obj, width, etc) {
    var bgcolor;
    if(typeof bgcolor_or_obj === 'object') {
        // Expand configuration object here.
        bgcolor = bgcolor_or_obj.bgcolor;
        width = bgcolor_or_obj.width;
        etc = bgcolor_or_obj.etc;
    } else {
        bgcolor = bgcolor_or_obj;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

I am aware of no standardized way in Javascript to differentiate between an argument passed to a function as being a variable or a literal. It is more likely that the function in question is checking if the first argument is an object, as demonstrated above.